# How to make overleaf not error-flag $ in source code

Tags: math-mode, listings, overleaf

I have the following piece of LaTeX code

```
We have that \lstinline[language=R]!glm(n ~ i, family = poisson)$dev! \( = -2l(\hat\theta) = - 2l(\hat\beta_0 + i\hat\beta_1)\).
```

Overleaf compiles it, but the editor error-flags the line, stating "open inline math ( used inside existing math mode $ unclosed $ found at \end{document}"

How to stop Overleaf from error-flagging the rest of my document (when my code is not erroneous)?

Comment: I fear this question is off-topic on the site. You should contact the overleaf support.

Comment: Yes, please send questions that are about Overleaf to Overleaf support (I'm on the support team, and glad to answer your questions there). Just to answer briefly, you can turn off code check globally or selectively: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Code_Check